# I don't know how to join table to another one in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables Reviews and Products

the reviews table have col1,col2,col3
the products table have col1,col2,col3

for example col2 in reviews table have the product id which is col1 in products table for example

I want to get the reviews for certain products ids

and also get the product info with the same statement

I don't have too much experience with these kind of operations

so any help is appriciated ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to setup model relations, this guide for it can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

Comment: Hi Quezler
I use query builder directly DB::table('..').. etc
I don't use any models